# Can I put the custom content on an external drive?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have a 500GB external hard drive, and I want store all the custom content files on it, to save space on my C drive. Will I be able to direct the game to look for them on the external hard drive?

Comment: [Tell Windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=move+my+documents+to+another+drive&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)  to move the entire My Docs folder to the new drive.